# Star Rating in Custom Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rest-api, javascript-controller, post

I was doing the trailhead 
[lightning-restaurant-locator](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-lightning-restaurant-locator) And the trailhead is showing how to use Get request so by looping through the response, name and views are in a list.
Now I want to add star for rating in each list so other contacts can also see what a person has rated the restaurant. I put the stars there but if I will refresh or go to other contacts it can remove.

[image]

So how can I add the star and post them for others to see the rating in lightning component. I am new to salesforce so facing some troubles.

*InTheArea.cmp*

```
<div class="slds-scrollable--y scroll-container" aura:id="scrollableArea">
      <ul class="slds-list--vertical slds-has-dividers--top-space">
          <aura:iteration items="{!v.restaurantList}" var="item" indexVar="i">
              <li class="slds-list__item" onclick="{!c.showDetails}" data-record="{!i}">
                  <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-m-bottom--x-small">{!item.name} </h3>
                  <img src="{!item.ratingImg}" alt="" class="ratingStars" />
                  <div class="slds-hide" data-details="{!i}">
                      <ul class="slds-list--vertical">
                          <li class="slds-list__item">{!item.address}</li>
                          <li class="slds-list__item">{!item.city}, {!item.state}</li>
                          <li class="slds-list__item">{!item.phone}</li>
                          <ui:button class="slds-button slds-button_success" label="RateTheRestaurant" press="{!c.handleClick}" />
                      </ul>
                      <div class="slds-media slds-m-top--medium">
                          <div class="slds-media__figure">
                              <img src="{!item.image}" class="slds-avatar--large slds-avatar--circle" alt="Placeholder" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="slds-media__body">
                              <p>{!item.review}</p>
                              <img src="/img/samples/stars_000.gif" class="imgEmp"/>
                              <img src="/img/samples/stars_100.gif" />
                              <img src="/img/samples/stars_200.gif" />
                              <img src="/img/samples/stars_300.gif" />
                              <img src="/img/samples/stars_400.gif" />
                              <img src="/img/samples/stars_500.gif" />                                  
                              <input type="text" id="text1" class="slds-input" placeholder="Review" />
                                <div class="rating_bar"> 
                                    <span class="rate_1" onclick="{!c.bandleClick}">1</span>
                                    <span class="rate_2" onclick="{!c.bandleClick}">2</span>
                                    <span class="rate_3" onclick="{!c.bandleClick}">3</span>
                                    <span class="rate_4" onclick="{!c.bandleClick}">4</span>
                                    <span class="rate_5" onclick="{!c.bandleClick}">5</span>                        
                                </div>
                              <div class="rating">
                <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>

      <ui:inputText label="Name" aura:id="fame" placeholder="First" change="{!c.getInput}"/>
        <!--<ui:outputText aura:id="nameOutput" value=""/>-->
           <ui:button aura:id="outputButton" label="Submit" press="{!c.getInput}"/>
<p>{!v.para}</p>
```

> InTheAreaController.js

```
handleClick : function(cmp, event) {
        confirm("Do you Really want to save this Form");
},
    bandleClick : function(cmp, event) {
        alert("Thanks for your Feedback!");
},
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFES! Please **[edit]** your question to include any code that you've written so far, so we can further assist you. Please read [ask] and take the [tour] for more information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. As I mentioned that I am new to salesforce so I added several form of stars for testing and add alert and confirm there

Comment: I am trying to get the concept that how Can I post the star rating fixed so others can also see. I feel there can be post request that can update the rest api and can fetch the star value so others can also see. However, I am not sure. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm) to store the value back to the record. There's also a [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_data_service) and [sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_example.htm) you can look at, too. There's lots of information on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I do this trailhead to get the complete idea.